# Making a query that works using one by one values, work for a bunch of values

Tags: mysql, sql, json, where-clause, lateral-join

I have this query that fetches results from a bunch of tables and functions (I use MySQL workbench).

It is like that:

```
SET @user_name := "any_username";
SELECT @user_id := user_id FROM main_db.user WHERE user_name=@user_name;
SELECT @available_balannce := JSON_EXTRACT(get_ewallet(@user_id),'$.available');
SELECT @current_commisions := JSON_EXTRACT(get_ewallet(@user_id),'$.current_commisions');
SELECT @commisions := JSON_EXTRACT(get_ewallet(@user_id),'$.commisions');
SELECT user_id, -- or you can use @user_id here. Since it's SET a bit higher
    user_name, 
    @available_balannce,
    @current_commisions,
    @commisions
    FROM main_db.user 
    where user_name=@user_name;
```

So if you type any of the usernames in the first row, it will fetch you the needed information. Result is of course a single line table that displays in the window of MySQL workbench.

Now I want to make that work with a bunch of usernames and preferably export that on the same window under several rows. I can then export that result. That will only be used through the Workbench interface. But I'm lost about how to do that looping process through the list of usernames.

I tried defining the list:

```
SET @user_list := (SELECT user_name FROM main_db.user WHERE user_name IN ("username1","username2","username3","username4"));
```

and then go through them with LIMIT and OFFSET

```
SET @user_name := @user_list LIMIT i,1;
```

But that didn't work. I was lost somewhere trying to figure it out syntactically I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need that many statements to generate thet result you want. Instead, you can do:

```
select
    user_id,
    json_extract(get_ewallet(user_id), '$.available'         ) as available_balance,
    json_extract(get_ewallet(user_id), '$.current_commisions') as current_commisions,
    json_extract(get_ewallet(user_id), '$.commisions'        ) as commisions
from main_db.user 
where user_name = @user_name;
```

Now this is easily extensible to handle several users at once. You would just change the `where` clause to an `in` condition, like:

```
where user_name in ('username1', 'username2', 'username3', 'username4')
```

In very recent versions of MySQL (8.0.14 or higher), you can use a lateral join, so the function is invoked only once per row:

```
select
    u.user_id,
    json_extract(e.ewallet, '$.available'         ) as available_balance,
    json_extract(e.ewallet, '$.current_commisions') as current_commisions,
    json_extract(e.ewallet, '$.commisions'        ) as commisions
from main_db.user u
left join lateral (select get_ewallet(u.user_id) as ewallet) e on true
where user_name = @user_name;
```

Comment: Excellent response. I had no idea LATERAL could be used in MySQL. I'm not very familiar with it and I'll keep it in mind to use it within this project.